# Using Express function to GET data from a PostGIS/PostgreSQL database and store inside a global variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express, postgis

Please excuse the (probably) silly question, as I am very new to this.

I need to create an endpoint that will 1) GET the ID of the user who is accessing the PostGIS database, and 2) store this ID in a global variable called 'current_user_id'.

I have already managed to GET the user's ID and return the result to the user's browser. Now I wish to simply store the result into a global variable, which I can use later. I would grately appreciate if somebody could assist with my problem.

Additionally, I would like this code to run as soon as the webpage is loaded.

Note I am using Node.js Express server

Let me know if you need any more info

Thanks :-)

```
// set up database connection and configure express
var express = require('express');
var pg = require('pg');
var fs = require('fs');
var crud = require('express').Router();

// identify file containing the connection parametres aka username/password.
var configtext = ""+fs.readFileSync("/postGISConnection.js");

// set up a connection pool to access the database
console.log(config);
var pool = new pg.Pool(config);

// ROUTE ENDPOINT 1: GET CURRENT USER'S ID

// create global variable to store result
current_user_id = "placemaker"

// get user_id from postGIS database using an Express function
crud.get('/getUserId', function(req,res) {
        
        // make a connection to the pool
        console.log("making connection to the pool...")
        pool.connect(function(err,client,done) {

        // condition: if connection fails, generate error. if connection works, create SQL query str
        if(err){
            console.log("was not able to make a connection to the pool " + err);
            res.status(400).send(err);
        } 
        var query = "select user_id from database.users where user_name = current_user;"
            console.log("created a SQL query to get the current user's ID")

        // run the SQL query and return error/results to a browser
        console.log("running the SQL query...")
        client.query(query, function(err,result) {
            done();

            // condition: if query fails, generate error. if query works, return results.                                            
            if(err){
                console.log("was not able to get the current user's ID")
                console.log(err);                        
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            console.log("successfully got the current user's ID")
            console.log("result(s):", result);
            res.status(200).send(result.rows);

            }); // end of function to run SQL query

        }); // end of function to create a connection to pool

    }); // end of 'get'

    console.log("current user_id from global variable is: ", current_user_id)
```

Comment: Are you talking about a serverside or clientside global variable?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for getting back to me. To clarify, I need to store the result into a server-side global variable.

Comment: No, you really don't want to do that. What if there are multiple users with different ids? At best, you can store the result in the request context, or a session variable.

Comment: What do you want to use that "global variable" for? The code excerpt you've shown tries to log it, but it does that before even the first request was handled, and before the database was queried.

Comment: Forgive my inexperience, it's all very new. My understanding is that I will need the user_ID stored in a global variable in order to query all the data at a later stage - e.g. showing data from a particular user. One of the parameters I will need to use to call my API is this user_id. Note this is only an 'introductory' assignment and I'm sure there are more robust ways of doing things, which I'm not currently aware of.

Comment: Yes, I defined the global variable before the request was handled - just as a placemaker. But I intend for this to be updated with the actual value returned e.g. "user123"

Comment: What do you mean by "at a later stage"? In a different request? Also how do you identify the "current user"?

Comment: I referenced a file ('/postGISConnection.js') that contains credentials that each user will have to access the PostGIS database i.e. user_name and password. My SQL query then selects user_id from the list of database users where user_name = current_user

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "each user"? Is every user running their own server, and only that user will connect to their own server?

Comment: "At a later stage" refers a seperate request.

Comment: As I say, I am already able to get the user's ID and push it to the browser. I just need to store the same result inside a global variable.

Comment: The assignment is designed to help us understand simple principles, and probably does not reflect best practice in 'real world' scenarios. I think for this example, we can think of the user running the server as the 'super user'. This user's credentials are used to query the database. I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. Yes, this is not a standard web application (you'd wouldn't put it on the internet), but it makes sense as a learning experiment. But still: you probably shouldn't use a global variable, http is meant to be stateless. What if the client makes the "second" request without sending `GET /getUserId` first? Either a) just make the database query again when handling the separate request b) accept the user id as a query parameter of the separate request (client first fetches it then passes it back) or c) since the current user never changes, query it once before starting the server.

Comment: If you're still determined to use a global variable, just put `current_user_id = result.rows` in the query callback, it'll work and you can access `current_user_id` from other request handlers. But beware of race conditions, you'll only get the value `"placemaker"` before the database query has run.